# Getting result in metric from QGIS Distance Matrix tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, distance

I'm trying to calculate the distance between points in layer with distance matrix tool. And keep getting strange results no matter what. Like this 
**MASTER**  ------------**SLAVE**  ---------------- **DISTANCE**  --------- **SHOULD BE**  
Metrotown ---------Knox Mountain ------ 0.036069979------------ 48.2 km 
Metrotown -------- Central  --------------- 0.048071058------------- 29.3 km
Metrotown -------- Rosedale ------------ 0.050883421-------------   60.1 km
Metrotown -------- Kelowna -------------- 0.051697257------------   340.4 km
Metrotown -------- Ocean Park --------- 0.054471001-------------    29.1 km
Metrotown --------  Langley --------------  0.055017692-------------    18.7km

First my thought was that the distance is in degrees not in meters. So I tried different CMSs but it didn't change anything. Than I tried to duplicate layer and calculate distances between points between two layers. But nothing changed. 
NAD83 CMS gave me another unrealistic result ( smth like 5665565, 5675656, etc)

What CMS I should use?

I even tried to do this in postgis with ST_Distance and still getting same results.

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20291/7913

Comment: I saw this post. It didn't make things clearer. I tried k=2 it gives same irrelevant results.

Comment: Although this is, on the face of it, an exact duplicate of  gis.stackexchange.com/q/20291/7913, I would urge leaving it open--at least in the meantime--because it is clear these distances are *not* in decimal degrees (they are too small); moreover, there is no apparent relationship at all between the numbers in the `distance` and `should be` columns: make a scatterplot and see!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to actually reproject your data to a new equidistant CMS, not just use the on-the-fly projection. Try that, and see if it helps!

Comment: It seems unlikely this problem is due to a choice of coordinate system: there is no consistent relationship between the true distances and the computed ones. Even if it happens to be fixed by reprojecting the data, that would not explain the bizarre results that have been obtained.

Comment: I did reproject it to 4 different CMSs. Most of them showing absolutely same thing. One ( Nad 83 - UTM 10) shows another irrelevant results like 665565, 5675656, etc

Comment: Ok. Looks like the layer is screwed up. I created test layer with 5 points and in NAD83 UTM 10 it's working fine. Thank you for your help. Not sure what to do with this layer now but probably it's not a common problem. Thank you for your help again