# Distance Matrix in QGIS, which SRID

Tags: srid, distance-matrix

I read several threads about it.. [How to get $length in meters in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/how-to-get-length-in-meters-in-qgis)
[Joining attributes from nearest point in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/how-to-join-attributes-from-nearest-point-in-qgis)
[QGIS, CRS's and metric measurements of distance matrix and nearest neighbour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108274/qgis-crss-and-metric-measurements-of-distance-matrix-and-nearest-neighbour)

and others, here and in other web sites. Nowhere I can find which SRID to use for calculating the distance in meters. My area of interest is the World...anyone please can help me??

Comment: what part of the world are you doing your distance calculations in? And what is the size of the area you're analyzing?

Comment: all France at the moment, but then I will need to analyze the whole world as I said...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for a solution to the same (or similar problem)...the SRID correct to obtain meters from the reprojection in QGIS is WGS84 UTM Zone 31N.Then it has to change in case you change country to analyze: check here to find out the correct time zone for each country http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm