# Distance Matrix in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, references, units

Can anyone help me with the distance matrix tool in QGIS? Is there a tutorial about it? It sometimes crashes when I use it and the values that it produces seem strange. I am a beginner in QGIS, so I extensely searched for a good tutorial, paper or document about the distance matrix plugin but I could not find something about it, which really helped me.

So I still have several questions:

Do my coordinates have to be all in the same CRS format? 
How can I produce the distance from a csv where I have many points and I want to get the distances from each point to each point in kilometers?

Are the results in degrees? How is that possible that a distance is measured in degrees?

I hope you can help me and am always happy for any constructive ideas or suggestions!

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20291/how-to-use-distance-matrix-tool-in-qgis

Comment: I Have not used the tool yet, but would propose to have both layers with same CRS, same as project CRS. Most favourite a projected CRS, not lat/lon. See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/how-to-join-attributes-from-nearest-point-in-qgis