# Distance Analysis from single point to multiple points on vector layers

Tags: qgis, vector, point, distance, spatial-analyst

Is it possible to do the following in QGIS:

Create a text file that plots the distance from a single point (stored in one layer) and multiple points (stored in another layer).

I have tried to use the Vector Distance Matrix tool but without success so far. Maybe this is not the right tool?

Please note that I have no programming experience and am reliant on tools and plugins!

Comment: That sounds like the right tool to use, are you receiving errors or blank file? Also, make sure the CRS for both layers and projection uses meters :)

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/how-to-join-attributes-from-nearest-point-in-qgis

Comment: its not measuring from the single point to each of the other points :( Which layer goes into which section on the selection screen? The single point (which is in the centre) has a random id of 3, is this ok?

Comment: @ClaireFeldkamp - The _Input point layer_ should be your single point layer; _Target point layer_ should be your multiple points layer. The id of 3 shouldn't matter, does your multiple points layer contain a field with **unique** values? You can easily create some by creating a new column with the expression `$rownum`.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I tried again just now and it seems to have worked! thank you