# Convert .osm.pbf file to a raster (tif, asc or rst)

Tags: raster, openstreetmap, convert, pbf

I downloaded the `.osb.pbf` file for my country, and I want to import it into [Graphab](https://sourcesup.renater.fr/graphab/en/home.html).

To import it, I need to have a *raster file* as the documentation file mentions:

> The second window is for importing the landscape map. It must be a raster  le (*.tif, *.asc, *.rst) in which the value of each pixel corresponds to a category (land cover or other classi cation).

I tried searching how to convert `.pbf` into raster, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Having the input file `map.osb.pbf`, how can I convert into `tif`, `asc` or `rst` so that I can use it in this app?

Related: [Finding "terminal" cities on the map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/265330/111144)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Graphab, but it likely won't just be a case of "converting" it.  You'll need to "extract only the data that you want Graphab to process" into one of its input files.  You can do some of that extraction work at the "OSM" side using osmfilter et al.