# Reassigning raster values by looking for nearest pixel in another raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have two **non-overlapping** rasters, A (red hues) and B (blue hues). I want to change the value of pixels in B via a nearest-neighbor search in A; i.e. a pixel in B with a value of 15 looks for the nearest pixel in A, finds a nearby A pixel with a value of 30, then the pixel in B changes from 15 to 30.

I can do this by converting both rasters to points and using distance matrix and joins as in [Joining attributes from nearest point in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/how-to-join-attributes-from-nearest-point-in-qgis), but it's slow and kind of cumbersome; is there an all-raster way to do this in QGIS?

[image: example]

Comment: I think you'll have to convert red to points anyway. Next step do eucledian allocation to these points. Con(~IsNull("blue"),"allocation)). Use lookup to convert results into floats.

Comment: That worked great in Arc, didn't even have to convert to points first, just fed Euclidian Allocation raster A and it gave a delauney triangulation raster.  Then the Con statement in raster calculator to re-assign B's pixels. Took 5 minutes to run Euclidian Allocation though, so hoping QGIS/GDAL can do it faster.

Comment: So they store integers. Makes a difference