# Assigning Elevation data from one point shapefile to another point shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am working with QGIS. I have a point shapefile with all my elevation data and a point shapefile with the coordinates for my project. I would like to assign the elevations from the elevation data to my project file.

Is there a possibility to do that without creating a raster in-between?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/joining-attributes-from-nearest-point-in-qgis. If I understand you right, it is a case for "Distance Matrix".

Comment: Unfortunately, this only helps partially. With the distance matrix I can assign the elevation from the nearest survey point. However, I would like an interpolation. If my project point is in-between three elvation points, then I would like that the elevation is interpolated from these three points.

Comment: Ok, then please edit your question to clarify what you want to have (to do) with the help of your comment.

Comment: Two things I would like to know: 1. the size of your point data (especially the "elevation" layer) and 2. why do you don't want to create a raster (interpolating; TIN; etc.)?