# Joining attributes between layers based on proximity of features

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, proximity

In QGIS 3.12 I have a Layer Y that has a specific attribute and my objective is to fill this attribute with information from Layer X regarding the proximity between the features of Layer X and Layer Y.

I'll exemplify below:

[image]

Point A and B are from Layer Y and Point 1,2,3 and 4 are from Layer X. I would like to know if it is possible to fill the attribute 'Address' from Layer Y with the attribute 'Address' from Layer X regarding the proximity of the features.

In this particular case I want to associate the 'Address' from Point 4 to the 'Address' from Point A, and the 'Address' from Point 3 to the 'Address' from Point B using the Field Calculator.

[image]

Comment: Especially [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/362033/109646) to the question shared by Taras should be helpful. I used the tool a lot during the last days.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Taras and Erik! I managed to find an answer that helped me a lot in the thread you linked @Taras@Erik!